# Ar Core Static GUI's on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Im surprised to be asking this, but my many searches are yielding **absolutely nothing**.

Im working on an AR application, in Android studio using ArCore & Sceneform.

It requires quite a bit of user input to provide some of the data for the AR Visualisations.

Im finding nothing about having a regular non ar menu system, in ARCore/Sceneform...i just want some kind of static interface akin to the regular android application gui type experience - Totally 2d and completely non-ar

Is this something that should be easy and straightforward, that im just over complicating? I already have an activity not in ArCore/Sceneform that does everything i need - I just simply need to push this data to the ar side any way i can.

Answer (score 0):

You can have regular UI elements, button, input etc in a number of ways in your AR Sceneform application including:

- using layouts to mix buttons and views with your Sceneform fragment
- using alert dialogs to display messages and get input from a user

An example of a layout that supports the AR view and 'floating buttons' is:

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/down_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/blank_button_bottom_right"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_downward_24px" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/blank_button_bottom_right"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_24px" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </RelativeLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

The above is simplified to make it more readable but you can see a full working example here: https://github.com/mickod/LineView

Using a dialog you can have a layout and code as below and add whatever EditText etc you need:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_info_text_view1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:text="@string/main_info_text1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_info_text_view2"
            android:layout_below="@id/main_info_text_view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:text="@string/main_info_text2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accreditations_info_text_view"
            android:layout_below="@id/main_info_text_view2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:text="@string/accreditations_text" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
    private fun infoDialog() {
        //Display an info dialog
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Info")
        val inflater = layoutInflater
        val settingsLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_layout, null)

        // Display the layout and react to ok
        builder.setView(settingsLayout)
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface, i ->
            return@setPositiveButton }
        builder.show()
    }
```

Comment: Dude, i can't thank you enough for the amount of effort you have put into this beautifully detailed response.

I have looked over line view and i think i have boiled my issue down to the following:

I need to have a fragment/tab that changes between my regular app Layout and my ArScene.

The floating buttons are great but the volume of controls and inputs im packing is large to the point that scrolling is essential. 

Ultimately im hoping i can use just floating button 1 to switch from my current ArFragment to my second tab/fragment.

Comment: @CorinHarper - that sounds like it would work. You can also have scrolling views in alter dialog is that is easier. You can use a floating button to cause the alert dialog tube displayed. The example above is actually called when a floating button is hit (I extracted it from some working code in another app).